# Python plotting with pyqtgraph from serial port while using labels and combo boxes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to plot telemetry data from an RC vehicle (not being specific because I want to apply this code for all kinds of projects, currently a rocket) to a computer using serial port. I want to show the COM port selection, connection status, and all kinds of data in labels and plots.

I am trying to use pyqtgraph but it is only allowing me to place a single plot filling my window.

How do I go about making a window that has multiple plots and labels in the same window?

This is my code so far.

```
#includes
import sys
import serial
import atexit
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
from time import sleep

#Beginning of code
class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        
        #Serial port object
        self.serialPort = serial.Serial()

        #Main window object
        self.setGeometry(100, 300, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Rocket Telemetry")

        #Available COMs label object
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl1.move(5,0)
        self.lbl1.setText("Available COMS")

        #Serial Port status label object
        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl2.move(200,0)

        #COM ports drop down list combo box object
        self.cbox_coms = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.cbox_coms.move(85,0)

        #Plot objects
        self.plots = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(self)

        # Some random data for scatter plot
        x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1000)

        # Add subplots
        plot1 = self.plots.addPlot(x=x, y=y, pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=0, title="Plot @ row 1, column 1")
        plot2 = self.plots.addPlot(x=x, y=y, pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=1, title="Plot @ row 1, column 2")
        plot3 = self.plots.addPlot(x=x, y=y, pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=2, title="Plot @ row 1, column 3")
        plot4 = self.plots.addPlot(x=x, y=y, pen=None, symbol='x', row=1, col=0, title="Plot @ row 2, column 1")
        plot5 = self.plots.addPlot(x=x, y=y, pen=None, symbol='x', row=2, col=0, title="Plot @ row 3, column 1")

        # self.pg_layout.showMaximized()

        #Show the main page maximized
        self.showMaximized()
     
    #If the user has not chosen an option for COM Port or has chosen "Disconnect", the the COM Port lists will be updated. otherwise, go to opening the serial port
    def updateComPorts(self):
        if self.cbox_coms.currentIndex() <= 0:
            print("Updating COM Ports")
            self.lbl2.setText("Disconnected!")
            self.cbox_coms.clear()
            self.cbox_coms.addItem("Disconnect")
            for port in comports():
                self.cbox_coms.addItem(port.name)
            QTimer.singleShot(1000,self.updateComPorts)
        else:
            QTimer.singleShot(1,self.checkSerialCom)

    #Serial port opening and closing takes place here
    def checkSerialCom(self):
        #If the serial port is open, check if the user wants to disconnect and close the serial port or if they want to change the serial port COM port
        if self.serialPort.is_open:
            if self.cbox_coms.currentText() == "Disconnect":
                print("Closing Serial Port")
                self.serialPort.close()
                self.lbl2.setText("Disconnected!")
                QTimer.singleShot(1000,self.updateComPorts)
            elif self.serialPort.port != self.cbox_coms.currentText():
                print("Changing Serial Port")
                self.serialPort.close()
                self.serialPort.port = self.cbox_coms.currentText()
                self.serialPort.baudrate = 115200
                self.serialPort.open()
                print("Opening Serial Port at", self.serialPort.port)
                while not self.serialPort.is_open:
                    print("Serial port is not open yet")
                    sleep(1)
                self.lbl2.setText("Connected!")
                QTimer.singleShot(1,self.readSerialData)
            else:
                QTimer.singleShot(1,self.readSerialData)
        else:
            if self.cbox_coms.currentText() == "Disconnect":
                self.lbl2.setText("Disconnected!")
                QTimer.singleShot(1000,self.updateComPorts)
            else:
                self.serialPort.port = self.cbox_coms.currentText()
                self.serialPort.baudrate = 115200
                self.serialPort.open()
                print("Opening Serial Port at", self.serialPort.port)
                while not self.serialPort.is_open:
                    print("Serial port is not open yet")
                    sleep(1)
                self.lbl2.setText("Connected!")
                QTimer.singleShot(1,self.readSerialData)
                
        
    #Read serial data
    def readSerialData(self):
        if self.serialPort.is_open and self.serialPort.in_waiting:
            print(self.serialPort.read())
        QTimer.singleShot(1,ex.updateUIObjects)

    #Update UI objects with new data
    def updateUIObjects(self):

        QTimer.singleShot(1,ex.updateComPorts)



print("\n\n\n\nProgram Started\n")
#main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = window()
    QTimer.singleShot(1,ex.updateComPorts)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563359/add-subplots-in-pyqtgraph/70798480#70798480).

Comment: @Domarm, when I try to switch my window() to pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(), everything breaks. Plus with this, I have to be tied to the columns and rows and I won't be able to position the labels wherever I want them

Comment: GarphicsLayoutWidget should be part of Your MainWindow, not to become main window itself. It's a widget which You can then put inside any PyQt Layout. You can for example create Window with any layout You want and each plot inside one GraphicsLayoutWidget. And then those layoutWidgets (with only one plot) can be inserted at any position within Your Layout inside MainWindow. For any more help I would need to see some code You are using.

Comment: @Domarm, Thank you for both quick comments. Here is my code with your suggestion included. But my window looks weird. Please take a look at the code and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer Your question, You need to gather some knowledge about layouts and element positioning.
In Your example, You are not using any layouts, only moving widgets to fixed positions in pixels. This approach might work for very limited cases, but it's strongly recommended to use Layouts.

Here is some [introduction](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-layout/) to it.

This will help You to make Your GUI look consistent in different windows sizes. As opposite to Your current approach, where You have to maximize Your windows size to see all the elements.

What if someone running Your app at resolution of only 800 x 600 pixels, while Your elements occupies 1024 x 768 screen size?
They simply won't fit to that screen.
**This issue can be solved by using layouts.**

Also have a look at very nice [designer tool](https://realpython.com/qt-designer-python/), which simplify the whole process of user interface creation.

To help You in Your current situation, You must again position Your plots and resize them, as they are not inside any layout.
So just as You did with Your label and Combobox, set position and size of Your plots:

```
self.plots.move(0, 35)
self.plots.resize(1024, 768)
```

This will move plots to pixel [ x=0, y=35 ] and resize them to 1024px x 768x pixels.

Comment: thank you for your help. One last additional question if you don't mind. How do I add another plot in the same plot in the code above?

Comment: If You mean subplot, just add another one with same approach `plot6 = self.plots.addPlot(x=x, y=y, pen=None, symbol='x', row=1, col=1, title="Plot @ row 2, column 2")`. Mind usage of row and col parameter. If You mean another GraphicsLayoutWidget, then just create `self.plots2 = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(self)` and add You plots `self.plots2.addPlot ...`. To place it, You have to again move it somewhere and resize it to fit Your window. You are welcome.

Comment: no I mean 2 lines or plots in the same plot. If I addPlot, then I am adding completely separate plot

Comment: I see. Just execute another plot method on parent plot. For example `plot1.plot(x, y)` will add second plot, execute another `plot1.plot(x, y)`  add third and so on...